# facebook,google & twitter authentication in nodejs

Tags: node.js

I'm working on web app. I need to authenticate with facebook, twitter and google to my web app,

I'm using nodejs please suggest me how to authenticate my web app with these.

Answer (score 2):

using passport module in nodejs provides you with various forms of authentication.

```
$ npm install passport
```

[passport guide](http://passportjs.org/guide/)

Answer (score 1):

oauth.io is a cool project to simply add OAuth to you app.

You can connect with a lot of providers, like facebook, twitter and google.

[link to oauth.io](http://oauth.io)

Answer (score 0):

you can use passport module http://passportjs.org/

or everyauth module https://github.com/bnoguchi/everyauth

This link have nice explanation of fb,twitter, google authentication with node.js http://scotch.io/tutorials/javascript/easy-node-authentication-linking-all-accounts-together